# Breakpoints are failing after upgrading to visual studio 2015?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am creating an ASP.NET MVC project in visual studio 2015. I recently took an old project that was originally 2013 and decided it was time to use visual studio 2015 instead. I also upgraded to entity framework 6. After making both of these changes and opening my old 2013 project in VS 2015, I am having some issues. My breakpoints are being ignored no matter what I try.

I have attempted to fix the breakpoints by:

- Disabling 'Just My Code' in Project Properties.
- Enabling/Disabled Native/Managed compatibility modes.
- Various settings changes in Tools > Project > Options > Debugging

I have read on this issue, and one user possibly fixed the breakpoint issue by creating a new project and re-importing everything. My project is fairly large, is there any other fix for my breakpoints other than doing a complete re-import? Thanks.